# Should I define variable in function as local in lua

Tags: lua

for example

```
function foo1()
    local i=10 --or just i=10
end
```

The variable `i` is not visible out of the function. So should I declare it as `local` explicitly. Or It's already a `local` variable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in Lua, every variable that's not explicitly declared `local` (except for arguments, because they are upvalue locals created implicitly by the VM) is a global, so doing this:

```
function foo1()
  i=10
end

foo1()
print(i) -- prints "10"
```

is exactly the same as:

```
_G["foo1"] = function()
  _G["i"]=10
end

foo1()
print(i) -- prints "10"
```

which is bad. so you should declare it as:

```
local function foo1()
  local i=10
end

foo1()
print(i) -- prints "nil", so it's local
```

EDIT: but mind the closure's upvalues.
e.g. this:

```
local function foo()
  local i=10
  local function bar()
    i=5
  end
  print(i) -- 10
  bar()
  print(i) -- 5
end

print(i) -- nil
foo()
print(i) -- nil
```

EDIT 2: also, you should consider making your functions local, so they don't bloat the global table. just declare them as `local function ......`

tl;dr: just make everything local unless you really have a good reason not to (=never), because that way you can't accidentally collide names. lua making everything global by default is a historical decision that's considered bad practice nowadays. one the reasons i like moonscript because it defaults everything to local (also the syntax is way nicer to me).

Comment: What does `upvalue` mean. What properties does this kind value have?

Comment: an `upvalue` is a variable that's usable by a function without being declared in that function but also not global. like declaring a local variable in a function that THEN declaring a function that uses the variable. like the `i` in my example: it's not global, but because `foo` declares it locally before declaring `bar`, `bar` can use it.

Comment: So What about an argument of a function. What does it belong to

Comment: an argument acts as a local. technically it's an upvalue, but that depends on the VM implementation, so you can safely assume it's local.

Comment: A local variable's lifetime is tied to the source code block (e.g. `do` ... `end`, or `function` ... `end`) in which it is defined. upvalues are former local variables whose lifetime has been extended beyond the scope of the defining block by being referenced by a closure (which is just a fancy name for a function referencing local variables defined outside the function's body). Function parameters are local variables until you create a closure which references them in which case they are transformed into upvalues.

Comment: To be clear (I think I'm agreeing with @siffiejoe), formal parameters are always effectively local variables. Just like local variables, only if you reference them in an inner function, are they upvalues.

Comment: @Samuel Actually, upvalue refers to a variable, not a value. It's a misnomer.

Answer (score 5):

This is stated clearly in the [online Lua ref manual, section 2.3](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.3):

> Any variable is assumed to be global unless explicitly declared as a local (see §2.4.7)